# Tensorflow dataset.batch() not showing the real batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to change the original queue based data load mechanism to `tf.data` API.

The original code is:

```
    # Index queue
    self.input_idxs = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, 2])
    idx_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(1e8, tf.int64)
    self.enq_idxs = idx_queue.enqueue_many(self.input_idxs)
    get_idx = idx_queue.dequeue()

    # Image loading queue
    img_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(opt.max_queue_size, task.proc_arg_dtype)
    load_data = tf.py_func(task.load_sample_data, [get_idx], task.proc_arg_dtype)
    enq_img = img_queue.enqueue(load_data)
    init_sample = img_queue.dequeue()

    # Preprocessing queue
    # (for any preprocessing that can be done with TF operations)
    data_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(opt.max_queue_size, task.data_arg_dtype,
                              shapes=task.data_shape)
    enq_data = data_queue.enqueue(task.preprocess(init_sample, train_flag))
    self.get_sample = data_queue.dequeue_many(opt.batchsize)
```

After the change, it is:

```
    # Dataset
    self.input_idxs = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, 2])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(self.input_idxs)

    def load_sample(idx):
        sample = task.load_sample_data(idx)
        sample = task.preprocess(sample, train_flag)
        return sample

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda idx: tf.py_func(load_sample, [idx], task.proc_arg_dtype), num_parallel_calls=self.num_threads)

    def gen(dataset):
        yield dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, tuple(task.proc_arg_dtype), tuple(task.data_shape))
    dataset = dataset.batch(opt.batchsize)
    self.iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    self.get_sample = self.iterator.get_next()
```

where `task.proc_arg_dtype` and `task.data_shape` are:

```
    proc_arg_dtype = [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32]
    data_shape = [
        [opt.input_res, opt.input_res, 3],
        [opt.output_res, opt.output_res, opt.det_inputs],
        [2, opt.max_nodes, 2],
        [4],
        [opt.max_nodes, opt.obj_slots + opt.rel_slots],
        [opt.max_nodes, opt.obj_slots, 5],
        [opt.max_nodes, opt.rel_slots, 2],
        [opt.max_nodes, 7],
        [1]
    ]
```

Since I find `tf.py_func` doesn't have `data_shape` argument so that I use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to do it. (Not sure whether it is correct since I met an issue before running compete)

The question is previously the `self.get_sample` is similar to:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(8, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(8, 64, 64, 300) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(8, 2, 200, 2) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(8, 4) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(8, 200, 9) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(8, 200, 3, 5) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6' shape=(8, 200, 6, 2) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7' shape=(8, 200, 7) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:8' shape=(8, 1) dtype=int32>]
```

Where the batch size is the first dimension. However by using `dataset.batch(opt.batch_size)`, the `self.get_sample` is

```
[<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(?, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(?, 64, 64, 300) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(?, 2, 200, 2) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(?, 4) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(?, 200, 9) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(?, 200, 3, 5) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6' shape=(?, 200, 6, 2) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7' shape=(?, 200, 7) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:8' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>]
```

Which not shows the real batch size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, to get a fully-defined static shape on the batched tensors, you need to tell TensorFlow explicitly to "drop" any "remainder" if the batch size does not divide the total number of elements evenly. To do this, replace the following line:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(opt.batchsize)
```

...with an application of [`tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder):

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(opt.batchsize))
```

Comment: As of tensorflow 1.10, the `drop_remainder` parameter has been added to `tf.data.Dataset.batch`.